# HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL - Tomcat

Tags: java, ajax, eclipse, tomcat

I know this has been asked many times before here, but after reading dozens of answers and solutions of other threads, I haven't been able to solve my issue.

I am currently working on a computer where I do not have administrative privileges, and my best guess is that the firewall blocks the server on localhost.

Here is my code:

#### GetTimeServlet.java

```
//I have tried overriding
public class GetTimeServlet extends HttpServlet 
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doPost (HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        newtest.DbQueries dbq = new newtest.DbQueries();
        out.print((int) Math.round(dbq.getSiteScore(sb.toString())));
    }
}
```

#### Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>exjobb</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>GetTime</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.GetTimeServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GetTime</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/get-current-time</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

#### index.html

I have a button which runs the following function `onClick="ajaxAsyncPostRequest('http://localhost:8080/ajaxdemo/get-current-time', $('#temp').val())`:

```
        function ajaxAsyncPostRequest(reqURL, temp)
        {
            temp = encodeURIComponent(temp);
            var params = "site=" + temp + "&userrating=" + $("#slider").val() + "&usercomment=" + $("#comment-textarea").val()
            + "&chkbox1=" + $("#sq_checkbox1").val() + "&chkbox2=" + $("#sq_checkbox2").val();

            //Creating a new XMLHttpRequest object
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            } else {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //for IE6, IE5
            }
            //Create a asynchronous GET request
            xmlhttp.open("POST", reqURL, true);

            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            //When readyState is 4 then get the server output
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) { 
                    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) 
                    {
                        gauge.refresh(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        //alert(xmlhttp.status);
                    }
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.send(params);
        }
```

The form-data is clearly sent in Post, and the server handles only Post requests. I'm not getting any errors or warnings either in Eclipse. What's going on here?

EDIT: I'm trying to do POST and **not** GET.

Comment: Did you check the status of your Ajax call in Dev Tools (F12) - Network tab ? What does it say ? You're using absolute URL like this `http://localhost:8080/ajaxdemo/get-current-time`, so you need to check if  context path (ajaxdemo) part is correct. Is that the same thing you see in other pages ?

Comment: If the URL is correct and the request is actually coming to your doPost method, try to add some loggers in that method and see

Comment: Did you check if there are any javascript errors in browser console ? Try to put an alert/console.log in your `ajaxAsyncPostRequest()` and see if the control is actually coming there when you click on that link

Comment: You could download a browser plugin REST client, make a POST request and test that it works as expected. That would rule out the server-side.

Comment: Also - simplify your code by dropping support for IE6 and earlier. No-one should still be expected to support those.

Answer (score 1):

for HTTP GET method you should define doGet method in your servlet (GetTimeServlet.java);

Comment: Indeed -- but I'm trying to do POST, not GET.